Размещение WPF .NET приложения на ПК с базой данных MS SQL через ADO .NET соединения
Есть готовое приложение, есть сервер баз данных и соответственно база данных на ней. Делал я всё на месте, где программа и требовалась, но появилась необходимость размещения точно такой же структуры на других компьютерах, без моего участия. Предполагается сделать архив с установочными файлами (SQL Server, MSSQL, возможно Visual Studio) для создания нового местного сервера баз данных с базой данных. Что можно сделать, что требуется сделать, что делать не стоит, и как можно решить этот вопрос?
Важно уточнить:

Локальной связи не планируется
Веб-сервер мне вероятно не подойдёт, т.к времени для всего этого тоже не найдётся
Постараюсь быстро ориентировать отвечающих по наличию вопросов


Много вопросов, а по факту не понятно в чем трудность. В чем сложность то?

Не до конца понимаю последовательность действий, и более конкретное изменение файлов для конкретной привязки. Например где переназначить имя сервера с копии проекта, есть ли необходимость ставить продукты для благополучной работы SQL, что необходимо поменять в app.confg и так далее

достаточно широкая тема + непонятна архитектура проекта, сомневаюсь что кто-то возьмется отвечать на этот вопрос. У дотнет шикарная документация, в том числе и по развертыванию приложений и по управлению конфигурациями, думаю стоит начать с нее. Определить последовательность действий по шагам и приступить

Если у вас приложение "портативно" в плане файлов и проблема только в базе, которую надо по новой "установить" на другом компьютере, то сделайте в программе возможность настройки подключения базы данных, ну и при первом подключении "восстанавливайте" эту базу из бекапа. Обычно за это отвечает "Миграция", но так, как вы пошли по хардкору, с ADO.NET, то... Как говориться, вы себе ССЗБ) Ну а если у вас это "учебный проект" (как тут у многих), для сдачи "диплома", то зачем вы тогда вовсе выбрали MySQL, непонятно... Тут надо выбирать SQLite и его аналоги, где база = файл лежащий в корне проекта.

Рад что мне ответили, но пока что ситуация все так же остается неясной. Отвечу сразу на оба сообщения. Учебная программа не предполагала развертки ПО для обычного пользователя, т.е исполнение данных функций лежит чисто на мне как на потенциальном программисте. SQLite мы не изучали, только сам слышал о такой вариации, видимо брали сразу "на вырост" (иначе я не понимаю почему, файл лежащий в корне проекта звучит гораздо лучше). ADO так же выдали как вариант работы с передачей данных, альтернативы увы не знаю. Я так полагаю, если и есть вариант, то сводится он к модификации отдельных файлов?

"SQLite мы не изучали" - А ее не надо изучать, это аналог обычной базы, но в виде файла, все SQL запросы аналогичны. Да, там есть свои тонкости, но для учебного проекта, как по мне, самое то. Так что, советую узнать. можно-ли использовать ее, тогда вам делать ничего по сути и не надо будет, передадите файл и все. "ADO ... как вариант" - ну если это не требование, то посмотрите в сторону EF, ADO в голом виде редко используется, а если перейдете на него, то смотрите на "Миграции" - это современный подход по изменению базы (включая ее создания).

Ну а так, как я сказал выше - делаете "бекап" базы, и повторяете при первом подключении эти SQL запросы, что восстановит базу. Также у MySQL, например, есть утилита для создания "дампа" и его последующего восстановления, через C# можно попробовать сделать что-то такое (там 2 варианта). Короче, вариантов много, самый правильный - миграция, изучайте, читайте, пробуйте.
